# Given a real sequence $\{ c_n \}$ does there exist a smooth function g such that $c_n = \int_0^1 t^n g(t) dt$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Are either of the following 2 claims correct?

Let $\{ c_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence. Suppose that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$ we have $c_n = 0$.

1. There exists $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(t) = f(2\pi + t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and
   \begin{align}
   c_n = \int_{0}^{2\pi} t^n f(t) \ dt \qquad \text{for all } n \in \mathbb{N}
   \end{align}
2. There exists $g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\text{support}(g) = [0,1]$ and
   \begin{align}
   c_n = \int_{0}^{1} t^n g(t) \ dt \qquad \text{for all } n \in \mathbb{N}
   \end{align}

Any advice or ideas on how to prove/disprove the claims will be greatly appreciated. If this result exists already, then a reference would be great.

EDIT: AN IDEA FOR PART 2

Let
\begin{align}
g(t) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_m t^m
\end{align}
on $[0,1]$ and $g(t) = 0$ elsewhere,
then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1 t^n g(t) dt &= \int_0^1 t^n \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_m t^m dt \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_m\int_0^1 t^{n+m} dt \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_m}{n+m+1} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} b_{nm}a_m
\end{align}
where $b_{nm} = 1/(n+m+1)$. Now we define the operator
$B : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ on the Hilbert space of summable sequences $\ell^2$ by

\begin{align}
B(a)_n = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} b_{nm} a_m.
\end{align}

If $B$ is surjective, then there exists an $a \in \ell^2$ such that $B(a) = c$. But is $B$ surjective? I think a similar argument may work for part 1.

Comment: Trivial necessary condition: the sequence needs to be bounded (why?!). Furthermore: if such a function exists (smooth or not, but integrable), it is unique (up to equality almost everywhere) - why? How does this latter observation help you?

Comment: Moreover $c_n=O(1/n)$ for 2. is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the observations PhoemueX and zhu. I've updated the question with the additional condition that $\{ c_n \}$ is null after sufficiently many terms. This condition suffices for my purposes, but may be slightly stronger than necessary.

Comment: PhoemueX, I can see now that $\{ c_n \}$ must be bounded, otherwise any choice of $f$ (or $g$) would be 'too small' for some sufficiently large $n$.  But why are the solutions $f$ and $g$ unique?

Comment: I think this is not possible if the sequence is finitely supported. The reason being that if you take all polynomials $(x^{N n})_{n \in \Bbb{N}_{\geq 1}}$ (with N arbitrary), then this family is dense in the set of continuous functions on $[0,b]$ that vanish at 0. One way to see this is as a consequence of the Müntz–Szász theorem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G(t)=t^{N+1}g(t)$, thus for all $n$
$$0= \int_{0}^1 t^n G(t)dt \quad (*)$$
As $P[x]$ is dense in $C([0,1], \| \|_{\infty})$, (*) implies that $0 = \int_{0}^1 |G(t)|^2dt$, or $G(t)=0$ atmost surely, or $g(t)=0$ almost surely.
Hence there is no such function.

*Side note:* Such function doesn't even exist even in $L^2([0,1])$ and "it does exist" in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$.